# EditText over ListView when KeyBoard appears

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-softkeyboard

So, I'm developing an application that have a Listview, an EditText and a Button below the ListView. Like this printscreen: [image]

The problem is: When I click in the EditText, the EditText rises and stay ahead my Listview, like this printscreen:

[image]

In my Mainfest I already add the windowSoftInputMode="AdjustResize" and windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and any works.

This is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="400dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Senha"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Conectar"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
              </RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: why you are not using LinearLayout?

Comment: and You write         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in both ListView and Button

Comment: Hey @Bruno Santons try adding this line to `EditText` : `android:layout_below ="@+id/listView"`

Comment: It's only a layout for tests, so I use the standard layout type. I remove the tag and didn't work :( @ChiragSavsani

Comment: @Josef thanks a lot for you tip, worked too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This. And Add margin according to your need.
I tested this in my mobile.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Senha"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:text="Conectar"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add RequestFocus below This snippet

```
 <ListView
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <RequestFocus/> 
</Relativelayout>
```